# Avoid saving empty string in database in android app

Tags: android, string, android-sqlite

I am building a TODO list app. I am able to save the strings and display them but the below given script also saves empty strings when Add button is clicked.

```
.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                                null,
                                values,
                                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                        updateUI();
                        db.close();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

to test if a string is empty:

```
String someString;
//...
if(someString != null && !someString.isEmpty()) {
    //do what you want with the valid string
}
```

in your code it will look like this:

```
 .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                        
                                String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                                if(task != null && !task.isEmpty()) {
                                    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                                    db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                                        null,
                                        values,
                                        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                                    updateUI();
                                    db.close();
                                } else {
                                    //should notify user that cannot enter empty task
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
```

Also you should not do long operations like opening, manipulating and closing your DB on the UI thread. long operations should be diverted from the UI thread to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit your UI such that the button is disabled as long as the text box is empty.

To check the text is empty use utility methods such as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: any idea how can i implement it ??